# The introduction of Python in C + + and the error in xstring

Tags: python

C PART

```cpp
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>  
    
    #include "Python.h"

using namespace std;
char* PyCall(const char* a, const char* b, const char* c) {
    Py_Initialize();
    if (!Py_IsInitialized())
    {

    }
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./')");
    PyObject* pFunc1 = NULL;
    PyObject* pFunc2 = NULL;
    PyObject* pFunc3 = NULL;
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule(a);
    if (pModule == NULL)
    {
        cout << "notfind";
    }

    pFunc3 = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, b);
    PyObject* args3 = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyObject* args2 = PyBytes_FromString(c);
    PyTuple_SetItem(args3, 0, args2);
    PyObject* pRet = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc3, args3);
    char* result = NULL;
    if (pRet)
    {

        result = PyBytes_AsString(pRet);
    }
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    char* res = PyCall("mytest", "codetest", "{'title':'Task Manager'}");
    cout << res;
}
```

Python Part

```py
def codetest(title):
    import win32gui
    import win32api
    import json
    dic = json.loads(title)
    a = win32gui.FindWindow(None,dic["title"])
    return str(a)
```

The basic Python library was imported successfully, but a runtime error occurred
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHbiW.png)

Exception thrown at 0x00007ff680271103 (in pycode. Exe): 0xc0000005: an access violation occurred while reading location 0x000000000000000.

Comment: This error occurs in XString, as shown in the image

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been resolved. The problem of the return value during the call resulted in cout error, and the parameter passed in python is bytes that needs to be decoded and transcoded. I didn’t read the C-API documentation carefully.